# validate email and come back to browser page in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a registration page and after registration is done, it takes me to page afterregistration and says that email verification link sent to your mail. I get this done in my register controller, but issue I face is , After email validation is done , it has to redirect to my another page say Emailvalidationsuccess. How to get this done.

Register Controller

```
  UserService.Create(json)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0) {
                      console.log(response)
                      FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                      $location.path('/afterregister');
                    } else {
                        FlashService.Error(response.json.response.statusmessage);
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        }
    };

})();
```

I found through stack that server side JSON request can have parameter URL and I can give my URL to redirect after email validation is done.How to give url which is there in my local machine to redirect. Like I have JSON request like this

```
{"json":  
       {"request":
                 {"servicetype":"21",
                  "functiontype":"1001",

                     "data":{
                            "email":"abc@gmail.com",
                            "password":"12345",
                            "retypepassword":"12345"
                           },
                        "url":""
                 }
        }
}
```

Comment: I found through stack that server side JSON request can have parameter URL and I can give my URL to redirect after email validation is done.